# Can no longer boot after updating Arch

Tags: arch-linux, boot, uefi

I am running Arch Linux with the Gummiboot boot manager. Everything was fine until I updated. I can't remember the exact packages that were updated but I'm pretty sure Gummiboot was one of them. Now when I boot I am just left with the Lenovo logo on my screen. The Gummiboot option is still appearing in my boot menu.

Update:
I have wiped my ESP and reinstalled gummiboot using the instructions here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Gummiboot

I then messed around with downgrading gummiboot and also installing GRUB instead to no avail. I have since reinstalled the latest version of gummiboot and downgraded the kernel and now I can boot again so I'm assuming its a bug.

Comment: Check your init settings from gummiboot (which I've never personally used). It may be either missing something or have something it doesn't need anymore. Hop into irc #archlinux on freenode. They're usually pretty knowledgable and quick to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility, and you should be careful to rule out any others before considering this, is that you have encountered what looks to be a bug with gummiboot where various kernels since at least 3.10.x (and possbly earlier) have simply failed to boot.

There have been a number of threads on the Arch boards documenting this issue, including this [last one about 3.12.2](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173654).

One way to determine if this is your issue is to use another UEFI boot manager like [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/index.html).

In the first instance, though, you should boot from a live medium, [chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chroot) and check pacman's log to see exactly what was updated. Make sure that gummiboot's files were successfully installed to the EFI, particularly if it is not mounted at `/boot/`.

Comment: Just had the same issue with gummiboot after upgrading to kernel 3.13.7 so I switched to grub

Answer (score 0):

> The gummiboot command by default assumes that your EFI System Partition is mounted on /boot. This means gummiboot in the ESP will not be updated automatically during pkg updates and you will have to call gummiboot --path=$esp update after every package update. Additionally you will have to make sure that the kernel and initramfs are copied onto the ESP as gummiboot cannot load EFI binaries from other partitions. It is therefore strongly recommended to mount your ESP to /boot if you use gummiboot, in which case updating will happen automatically by the post_install script of gummiboot during package updates.

from the [gummiboot archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gummiboot) page

This is possibility!

Comment: Thanks but I already mount to /boot. I'm thinking of wiping my ESP and reinstalling gummiboot using a live USB stick